# How to save one of two checkbox in localstorage without a button

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, local-storage

I have two checkboxes to choose between two payment-methods. If the form shows an error in the fields, the page reloads.

Now the first payment-method should be always selected as the first, but if the user checked and filled out the second payment-method, with an error, the page jumps always back to the first payment-method.

I tried to solve the problem with localstorage, but failed trying.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="sepa" id="SepaCheckbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse#sepa" data-text="Collapse" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="kreditkarte" id="kreditkarteCheckbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse#kreditkarte"
  data-text="Collapse">
```

```js
window.onload = onPageLoad();
function onPageLoad() {

  let checked = "true" == localStorage.getItem("checked");
  jQuery("#kreditkarteCheckbox").prop('checked', checked);

  if (jQuery(".kreditkarte").is(':checked')) {
    jQuery('.sepa').removeAttr('checked');
    jQuery('#kreditkarte').addClass('show');
  } else {
    jQuery('#sepa').addClass('show');
    localStorage.removeItem('checked');
    jQuery('.kreditkarte').removeAttr('checked');
    jQuery("#kreditkarteCheckbox").removeAttr('checked');
  }
}

jQuery('#kreditkarteCheckbox').click(function() {
  let checked = $("#kreditkarteCheckbox").is(":checked");
  localStorage.setItem("checked", checked);
});

jQuery('.sepa').click(function() {
      if (jQuery('#kreditkarte').hasClass('show')) {
        jQuery('#kreditkarte').removeClass('show');
      }

      if (jQuery('#kreditkarteCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
        jQuery('.kreditkarte').removeAttr('checked');
        jQuery("#kreditkarteCheckbox").removeAttr('checked');
      }
      jQuery('.kreditkarte').removeAttr('checked');
      localStorage.removeItem('checked');
      jQuery("#kreditkarteCheckbox").removeAttr('checked');
    });

    jQuery('.kreditkarte').click(function() {
        if (jQuery('#sepa').hasClass('show')) {
          jQuery('#sepa').removeClass('show');
        }
        if (jQuery('.sepa').is(':checked')) {
          jQuery('.sepa').removeAttr('checked');
        }
});
```

Comment: your first problem is `window.onload = onPageLoad();` this is calling a function and then setting the return value of that function to the window.onload property. since that function does not return anything you're not doing anything onload. you want to instead just set the function to the onload value: `window.onload = onPageLoad;`

Comment: the next problem is you didn't provide the whole code. it looks like you're missing some closing brackets.

Comment: And you don't have full code including full html that is used in JS and including all libraries used in script tag in html, then don't use stack snippets. They are used to actually run the code and test it.

Comment: I updated the code. And were using library = "/jQuery/jquery.min.js"